# Scaling of minimal surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

*After scaling and suitable Euclidean motions every rigid minimal patch can be placed on a unit catenoid of revolution $ x^2 + y^2 = c^2 \cosh^2 (z/c), c=1.$ with full area contact.*

Is the statement correct? To me it appears to be so as principal curvatures $ |\kappa_1| = \kappa_2 =  c/r^2 $ involve a single constant, so mean curvature vanishes.

EDIT1:

In such a case if $\psi$ is angle of reference direction to line of curvature, then for the constant $c$  we have

$$ c\, \kappa_n = \cos 2 \psi  ;  c\, \tau_g = \sin 2 \psi. $$

Comment: What do you mean by applied onto?

Comment: Used in Minding's theorem, but it is different, involving isometric mapping/bending ...shall change it.